# How to get tex4ht ODT output to respect \clearpage

Tags: tex4ht

I have a LaTeX document which has some `\clearpage`s issued and which I'm trying to convert to ODT using `tex4ht`. While it is understandable that `\clearpage` is ignored in html output, it would also make sense to have it considered in a ODT output.

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Processed with:

```
make4ht -f odt document.tex
```

Will output a single page:

[image]

How could I get the `\clearpage` respected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\csname append:def\endcsname\clearpage{\Hclearpage}
\EndPreamble
```

It appends `\Hclearpage` command  after `\clearpage`. This command inserts:

```
 <text:p text:style-name="clearpage"></text:p>
```

It requests the page break:

[image]

Comment: Nailed it, yet again! Thank you. One detail, for the config file, is there a way to call it implicitly (that is, not as an explicit command option)? (like with the equivalent for `filename.mk4` for a `filename.tex` on the local directory). This would facilitate my automation of things.

Comment: @gusbrs you can add it in the [configuration file](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht#configuration-file-configfile), using `set_settings{tex4ht_sty_par = "cfg_file_without_extension," .. settings.tex4ht_sty_par}`

Comment: michal.h21 Thank you, but I cannot follow the whole chain. When I read the documentation I thought those are the places where `.cfg` would be found by `make4ht`. If I understand your suggestion, if I add this line to a file named `.make4ht` located in the documents' directory and have a file named `filename.cfg` also in this directory running `make4ht` on `filename.tex` will find the `.cfg` file automatically. Is that correct? Would it be also possible to set this in the `.mk4` file?

Comment: I got it to work with `.make4ht`. Thank you!

Comment: @gusbrs I think you should specify path to the cfg file, it won't be found automatically if it was in different folder than your TeX file, or somewhere `kpsewhich` can find it (so it can be somewhere in the local TEXFMF tree, like `~/texmf/tex/latex/mycfg/mycfg.cfg`)

Comment: michal Yes, I was able to get it to work after all, using the cfg file. Thank you!

Comment: Just noticed this one also made it to the latest update. Thank you very much!

Comment: @gusbrs yes, but it will be removed in the next update, I've found that it breaks lot of things. It seems that only safe option is to use a custom macro in the document. Btw, I've started to work on a new ODT export, so it will be possible to use filters and fix some issues with math etc.

Comment: Mmh, I'll leave it out of my own settings then. Thank you for letting me know. As to the new ODT export, I'm looking forward to it. I still have some unfinished business with my settings, and should be able to report new issues eventually (here or at GitHub, as appropriate). But this week will be busy around here, that will have to wait a bit.

Comment: @gusbrs I am making slow progress, I am not even sure that I will answer all your questions from last week this week, so I am OK with that :)

Comment: I'm OK with that too. ;)

Comment: @gusbrs I've finished the new version of `ODT` support in the development version of `make4ht`, so it is ready for testing :)

Comment: michal, That's great news! And actually quite fast! :) Thank you very much!! (I'll be traveling in a couple of hours and will thus be "off grid" for the remainder of the week. But I should be able to catch up by the weekend and will report back as soon as I can.)